# PHP string replace of "&"

Tags: php, string, replace

I am currently replacing spaces with an underscore during an image upload.
How can I also include it so it changes & to "and".

```
$newname = str_replace( ' ', '_', trim( strip_tags( $_POST['name'] ) ) ) . _ . $formKey->generateKey() . '_' . time() . '.jpg';
```

Kind of stuck with this one and don't know what to even attempt..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$newname = str_replace(array(' ', '&'), array('_', 'and'), ... );`

Comment: I think you meant the other way around. Replace spaces with an underscore, not "&". Also, replace "&" with "and.

Comment: @cillosis The above replaces spaces with underscores and & with "and". [PHP: str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)